# How to solve error of node-gyp running yarn install

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to run yarn install on a project and I got the following issue and have no clue what to do.

My versions:

```
- node -v v15.2.1
- npm -v 6.14.10
- node-gyp -v v7.1.2

error /Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/deasync: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/deasync
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@15.2.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/deasync/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/deasync',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `c++ -o Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o ../src/deasync.cc '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=deasync' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/include/node -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/src -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/deps/uv/include -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/deps/zlib -I/Users/jake/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.2.1/deps/v8/include -I/Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/node-addon-api  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o.d.raw   -c'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o] Error 2
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jake/Dropbox/My Mac (Jakub’s MacBook Pro)/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v15.2.1
```